# SQL Server 2012 foreign key constraint trigger

Tags: sql-server, database, triggers

I am new to triggers and I have created a trigger to check foreign key constraints across tables in different databases. I know this shouldn't be done however this is the only solution that I could find to resolve my issue with foreign key constraints. The trigger does work however it does not tell me what record caused the violation when the insert script has more than one record to insert. I am looking for a way that the trigger could tell me the record with 'x' primary key and 'y' foreign key was the one to fail. Currently, it runs thru the script comes across a violation, throws the RAISERROR, rolls back everything and nothing gets inserted in the database. Below is my script -

```
Create Trigger AV.fkConstraintTrigger ON [AQB_MON].[AV].[NAAQValue]
    FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
SET NOCOUNT ON;

IF EXISTS (
    SELECT *
    FROM INSERTED AS I
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (
        SELECT *
        FROM [AVData].[dbo].[SourceParameterTemplate] AS A
        WHERE I.[SourceParameterTemplateID] = A.[SourceParameterTemplateID]
    )
)
BEGIN
    RAISERROR('Violation of foreign key constraint',16,1);
    ROLLBACK;
END

END
```

**UPDATE**
I made changes to the script based on the comments below because I would rather have them displayed in the message then in a separate table. However when I do I get two 'Incorrect syntax near' errors. First being the '=' and the second is the last ')'. I cannot see what would cause them.

```
Create Trigger AV.testfkTrigger ON [AQB_MON].[AV].[NAAQValue]
    FOR INSERT, UPDATE
AS
BEGIN
    SET NOCOUNT ON;
    Declare @SourceParameterTemplateID varchar(25)
    IF EXISTS (
        SELECT TOP 1 @SourceParameterTemplateID = [SourceParameterTemplateID]
        FROM INSERTED AS I
        WHERE NOT EXISTS (
            SELECT *
            FROM [AVData].[dbo].[SourceParameterTemplate] AS A
            WHERE I.[SourceParameterTemplateID] = A.[SourceParameterTemplateID]
        )
        order by [SourceParameterTemplateID]
)
    BEGIN
        RAISERROR('Violation of foreign key constraint',16,1, @SourceParameterTemplateID);
        ROLLBACK;
   END
END
```

Comment: Well....you could make your error message contain that information. You know how to get the data already as you posted the query above. You could include all rows that caused the violation. And of course since you are raising an error is it going to rollback the entire transaction, not just the row(s) that are invalid.

Comment: This looks a LOT like sql server. Do you also use mysql? If not, you should remove that tag.

Comment: I was thinking along those lines however I don't know how to get the information into the message and I cannot find any examples.

Comment: So... why can't you use a foreign key for this? Anyway to get your info into the message I suggest you select the TOP 1 record into some variables like this `SELECT TOP 1 @Key1Variable=Key1, @Key2Variable=Key2 FROM INSERTED .... ORDER BY Key1, Key2`. Now you have some values in variables `@Key1Variable` and `@Key2Variable` that you can append to your error message.

Comment: @nick, he can't use an FK because the two tables are in different databases.

Comment: Oh sorry I didn't read properly.

Comment: I tried to use SELECT TOP 1 @Key1Variable = SourceParameterTemplateID however it doesn't like the equal sign. It gives me an 'Incorrect syntax near = '

Answer (score 1):

Putting the data into the error message is not very useful.  What would make more sense is to create and exception table that stores the data and possibly any other useful fields like the time of the problem and the user who sent in the bad data.
If you temporarily put the info into a table variable, then you can insert to the exception table after the rollback as the table variable is not rolled back.

Then your application can look up the data in the table if an error is returned from the insert/update.